# Does linker add the library function into the source code?

Tags: c

Linker basic function is to link the object code with other object code(it can be standard library code).

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("hello");
}
```

I want to know will linker replace the printf() function with its definition (like an inline function in c++). Or it will paste the printf()
function outside the main() function and pass "hello" as  argument to that function.

Comment: Neither. For standard dynamic linking it'll reference the external `printf` function in the libc supplied by the system.

Comment: @Aplet123 as far as i know in c function must be present in the exe file for the execution ,then how will it work if there is no printf?

Comment: Dynamic linking uses libraries. The program loader makes sure the libraries are loaded into the virtual address space of your process before your process starts executing. So no need for all functions to be present in an image.

Comment: Of course, it is also possible to use static linking. Your image file will be bigger if you do that.

Comment: is there any command to use dynamic or static linking?

Comment: ***`Does linker add the libarary function into the source code?`*** Linker does not add anything to the source code. Only the programmer can add something to the source code

Comment: `is there any command to use dynamic or static linking?` yes. Read your toolchain documentation

Answer (score 4):

For `printf("hello");`, the compiler generates an instruction to call a subroutine. It leaves the address of the subroutine not completely filled in. The object module the compiler generates has some notes about what routine’s address should be filled in there.

The linker may work in different ways. For static linking, the linker will find the implementation of `printf` in a library and copy the object module for it from the library into the executable file it is building. Depending on certain characteristics of the link, the linker might then complete the call instruction with the final address of the `printf` routine or it might leave notes in the executable file about the relationship between the call instruction and the `printf` routine. Later, when the program is being loaded into memory, the program loader will complete the address in the instruction.

For dynamic linking, the linker will find the implementation of `printf` in a library (or in a file with sufficient information about the library). It will not copy the `printf` function’s object module into the executable file, but it will include notes about the relationship between the call instruction and the `printf` routine and its library in the executable file. Later, the program loader will copy the `printf` function’s object module into the memory of the process. (This might be done by mapping part of the process’ virtual address space to physical memory that already contains the object module from the library and that is shared by other processes on the system. This sharing reduces the load on the system and makes dynamic loading more favorable in this regard.) And the loader will complete the address in the call instruction.

Some dynamic loading is not done as soon as the program is loaded. When a process is started, the loader might load just the program entry point and some essential parts. Some call instructions might be left incomplete. They will have been filled in with the addresses of special subroutines of the program loader (or dynamic library loader). When one of these subroutines is called, it will then load the desired routine, change the address in the call instruction (or otherwise arrange for future calls to call the desired routine), and then jump to the desired routine. This is beneficial because routines that are not used by your program in a particular run do not have to be loaded into memory at all. For example, if your program has a lot of code and data to log errors and inform the user when certain errors occur, that code and data does not have to be loaded into memory of those errors do not occur in a particular session.